# How to determine coordinates of view during custom transition animation in IOS 7 after a orientation change?

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview, orientation-changes, custom-transition

A quick summary of my issue:

I am using the View Controller Transitioning API in iOS 7 to create a custom transition that expands a cell in a uicollectionview to a fullscreen view when tapped, and shrinks back to the original coordinates when closed.

Similar to what the Photos app and Facebook does.

It works great in both orientations as long as I remain on the same orientation presenting and dismissing the fullscreen view.

It fails if I were to change the orientation while in the full screen view before dismissing it.

Some details:

I am using a navigationController to segue from View1, which contains the collectionView, to View2 which is the fullscreen view.

View1 implements the UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol, and in the navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController: method I calculate the coordinates that the animation has to start from when the operation is a "Push" and likewise the coordinates the animation has to finish on when the operation is a "Pop" before returning the UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning class that does the animation.

I calculate the start and ending frames in the coordinate system of View1 in the following manner:

I retrieve the selected cell:

```
        PhotoCell *cell = (PhotoCell *) [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];
```

I convert the frame of the cell to View1's coordinate system in the following manner:

```
self.originatingFrame = [cell.contentView.superView convertRect:cell.contentView.frame toView:self.view];
```

When keeping the rotation constant between the Push and the Pop operation this calculation returns the same coordinates both times and the result is what one would expect. The animation starts from the frame of the cell and shrinks back to the same cell.

However; when rotating the device between the Push and Pop operations, I get incorrect results. The coordinates calculated during the Pop are exactly the same as it was during the Push. It is as if View1 and the collectionView have not rotated yet. Thus the animation ends where the cell would have been if the device had not rotated.

How can I calculate the coordinates of the selected cell to account for the rotation change during the Pop operation?

Thanks